# Repeating formData to Go struct

Tags: go, multipartform-data, gorilla

I am submitting a repeating form, where the resulting formData is parsed as:

```
"Name":  {"John", "Jake"},
"Phone": {"999-999-999", "12312-123-123"},
```

However, I want to structure to be

```
{ Name: "John", Phone: "999-999-999" }, 
{ Name: "Jake", Phone: "12312-123-123" }.
```

I'm told [gorilla/schema](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema), is a good fit, but I tried it below and it produces an empty slice. Is there something I am missing?

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"

        "github.com/gorilla/schema"
)

type Person struct {
        Name  string
        Phone string
}

func main() {
        values := map[string][]string{
                "Name":  {"John", "Jake"},
                "Phone": {"999-999-999", "12312-123-123"},
        }
        var persons []Person
        decoder := schema.NewDecoder()
        decoder.Decode(persons, values)
        fmt.Println(persons)
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that while most browsers will submit form fields in the order they appear in the HTML, there is technically no guarantee this will be the case, so relying on the ordering of multiple fields with the same name may be dangerous. You might consider sequential naming of fields to be certain that `name1` goes with `phone1`, because `name[1]` and `phone[1]` might not.

Answer (score 1):

In your provided data of json each key contains two values. That's the reason behind empty slices. Use slice of string in your struct to unmarshal the value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gorilla/schema"
)

type Person struct {
    Name  []string // this should be a slice since the key contains multiple values
    Phone []string
}

type Person2 struct {
    Name  string
    Phone string
}

func main() {
    values := map[string][]string{
        "Name":  {"John", "Jake"},
        "Phone": {"999-999-999", "12312-123-123"},
    }
    person := new(Person)
    decoder := schema.NewDecoder()
    decoder.Decode(person, values)
    fmt.Println(person)
}
```

**Output:**

```
&{[John Jake] [999-999-999 12312-123-123]}
```

For required structure

```
{ Name: "John", Phone: "999-999-999" }, 
{ Name: "Jake", Phone: "12312-123-123" }
```

**Edited:**

Process the data coming from form to change the format of your structure.

```
type Person2 struct {
    Name  string
    Phone string
}

func processData(person *Person) {
    var result []Person2
    var person2 Person2
    for i := 0; i < len(person.Name); i++ {
        person2.Name = person.Name[i]
        person2.Phone = person.Phone[i]
        result = append(result, person2)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", result)
}
```

**Output:**

```
[]stack.Person2{stack.Person2{Name:"John", Phone:"999-999-999"}, stack.Person2{Name:"Jake", Phone:"12312-123-123"}}
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/ja9t2-D8Wik) to process the data

As @Adrain suggested it is better to use some kind of indexing with the field names for the form. It is also provided in [`gorilla/schema`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema) package to name the values with indexes for saving multiple records.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Name">
    <input type="text" name="Phones.0.Label">
    <input type="text" name="Phones.0.Number">
    <input type="text" name="Phones.1.Label">
    <input type="text" name="Phones.1.Number">
    <input type="text" name="Phones.2.Label">
    <input type="text" name="Phones.2.Number">
</form>
```

Above form can be parsed to below struct which contains a slice of Phone:

```
type Person struct {
    Name   string
    Phones []Phone
}
```

Comment: How would you process the data though?

Comment: looping over the data and then assign it to a different struct as per your requirement. Or simply implement unmarshal interface

Comment: @hendry Please check edited code to process the data according to your requirement